# Using multiple mockFor() in grails 2.2.3 unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.2

I want to write a unit test for my controller which uses multiple services inside it.
How can I use multiple mockFor() for services?
Tnx.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about how to use multiple `mockFor`, or asking more generally how to create multiple mocks?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for replying, my question is how to use multiple mockFor() when my controller uses multiple services inside it.

Comment: "my question is how to use multiple mockFor() when my controller uses multiple services inside it." - The accepted answer doesn't use any `mockFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example using spock for testing:

```
class ExampleControllerUnitSpec extends Specification {
    def anyService
    def anotherService


    def setup() {
        anyService = Mock(AnyService)
        controller.anyService = anyService

        anotherService = Mock(AnotherService)
        controller.anotherService = anotherService
    }

    def "test"(){
        when:
            controller.action()
        then:
            1 * anyService.doSomething() >> "result"
            3 * anotherService.doSomethingElse() >> "result2"
    }
}
```